# What's a good word to describe adults who are not yet parents?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, kinship-terms

Just read this in Emma Donoghue's book ["Room"](http://www.roomthebook.com/). Is there a word for adults who are not parents?

Comment: As a parent, I have often thought that adults who don't have to care for children are not real adults. They are themselves grown-up children, because they've never had to think of anyone's happines but their own. ;=)

Comment: The question is ambiguous. Do you mean an adult who is not a carer for any other person, or an adult who does look after a person but is not that person's parent?

Comment: @roviuser: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joke

Comment: As a parent, I have often thought that adults who don't have children must be the LUCKIEST PEOPLE IN THE WORLD, because they never have to think of anyone's happiness but their own. And they aren't in for 100K$ per child for college expenses.

Comment: @Robusto: I've met plenty of parents that still only think of their own happiness ;P

Comment: @Robusto and @horatio -- as a childless, married, adult, I can assure you that not all of us are lucky, selfish, grown-up children.  Many of us spend hundreds of hours a year with other peoples' children, especially those children who don't have functional parents.  We're still part of the village.

Comment: @Steve Melnikoff: good comment. My initial thought was around biological parents. Other models apply as well of course, but from the answers posted below so far, it seems that there is no clear-cut word.

Comment: @Robusto - [This be the verse.](http://www.poetryfoundation.org/poem/178055)

Comment: @MT_Head, that poem was my credo -- until I had kids myself. I still love it, though! I feel for my kids ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Adults".

The word "adult" does not imply that one is a parent, so there is no need for a word that describes a childless adult.

Comment: Or a featherless adult, for that matter.

Comment: It's worth noting that in some contexts, "virgin" has simply meant "women who does not yet have children" rather than the perhaps more modern, as it were, "not yet had sex".

Answer (score 7):

- childless (comes with the expectation of adult and married)
- barren (more about the inability to have children rather than the state of lack thereof)

Answer (score 5):

Doing a wikicrawl revealed these two terms:

- DINK or [DINKY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DINKY) — dual (or double) income, no kids (yet)
- [childfree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childfree) — individuals who neither have children nor desire to have children

Both of these hold a lot of connotation. DINK is somewhat derogatory; childfree is almost seen as a lifestyle choice similar to vegetarianism or recycling.

Comment: The only good answer.

Answer (score 2):

As MikeVaughan proposed, Guardian seems a logical choice for someone who's with you in order to protect you in some fashion, but who is also not your parent.

May I also propose *bachelor*?  That also implies someone who isn't married, but if that applies in your case, then this would be another possibility.

Comment: Bachelors can have children.

Comment: Technically, so can barren adults or guardians.  Though I think you'd be hard-pressed to assume someone having children after calling him a bachelor, and ultimately interpretation is what counts.

Comment: very true.

Answer (score -1):

Childless adults are called **[Childfree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Childfree)**.

Comment: So, why did you post that? It's right there in MrHen's answer, posted three years ago.