# Is there a specific English word for a woman that has not given birth yet?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a specific English word for a woman that has not given birth yet? I don't mean a sterile woman. I mean a young woman, who is not pregnant, who hasn't got children, who hasn't given birth.

The young woman hadn't had children, but wanted them in the future. She was a typical _____.

Comment: If you have discarded one or more words then you should mention them in your question and explain why they do not satisfy you. Users cannot read minds. :(

Comment: Please supply a sentence where you would use this word (Must it really be a single word? Can it also be an idiom?) For example, "Pregnant and ____ women are blah blah blah...". Use a complete sentence, please.

Comment: I used "women that have not given birth yet" . I'm not satisfied with my choice, but it will do. The first suggestion "nullipara"is the exact one, but its too formal.  Thank you very much for your answers and comments!

Comment: Well, stick around. There's probably an American or two who can suggest a more modern and more sensitive expression than "childless", one that will also be shorter than your chosen phrase (which works fine by the way).

Comment: The word would have to cover a woman who has miscarried.

Comment: Also relevant: [How to describe a person who does not want children?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/395716/177853) (The title says "person" but the question actually specifies a woman.)

Comment: @Gergana For extra context, is there such a word in your native language?

Comment: @Mitch [нерожавшая](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=hChDW7T-CciVsAHp-7jgBg&q=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F+in+english&oq=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F+in+english&gs_l=psy-ab.3...2187.5841.0.6428.11.11.0.0.0.0.307.2154.0j7j3j1.11.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.8.1619...0i19k1j0i13i30i19k1j0i10i30i19k1j0i30i19k1j0i8i13i30k1j33i21k1.0.7OBPgcu3Vl0) ... possibly. It's a single word I found online

Comment: @Gergana Could this woman ever have been pregnant at any point in her life but not given birth at all? Or does she need to never have carried a child in her womb?

Comment: Please re-read the [tag:single-word-requests] tag description, particularly the emphasised part: "*YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used*".

Comment: @Mari-LouA Is that the OP's native word for what she describes? She would know better if that is a highly formal medical term vs an informal term.

Comment: *who hasn't got children* - Not even adopted children or just not any she's given birth to? Is it important that the word only apply to young women specifically?

Comment: Reminder to everyone: answer in answers, not in comments. Comments don't have the quality assurance mechanisms that answers do.

Comment: [what do you call a person who has chosen not to have children?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343634/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-has-chosen-not-to-have-children)

Comment: Also note that the **yet** part of your question is a bit presumptuous. Not all women will give birth. Not all women want to give birth.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**nullipara**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nulliparous) (condition of nulliparity)

n.

> A woman who has never given birth. Never having borne a child.
>   Synonym(s): nonparous

Comment: I saw this word in the medical dictionary. I meant more conversational word. Thank you!

Comment: very few people will know what you are talking about if you use this word

Comment: I heard the word was "nullparous".  Same thing I'm sure.  But if you want something more colloquial, try "child-free".  (And just what do you mean by "yet", anyway?)

Comment: I just commented on this answer but it seems to have gone away.  Anyway, try, try, again.  I heard the word ^ was nullparous, which I'm sure is the same thing.  But if you want something more colloquial, try childfree.  (And just what do you mean by "yet" anyway?)  For someone who doesn't want children, I immediately think of nonbreeder, but that doesn't go down too well.  EDIT: my previous comment just popped up again.

Comment: @Jennifer I would guess that nulliparous is the adjective form and nullipara the noun.

Comment: "Child-free" is a politically loaded term with a strong connotation of not wanting children at all.

Comment: @Jennifer Child-free also isn't specific to gender or age though it isn't clear from the question how important it is that the word imply you're talking about a young woman. (On the other hand, child-free also implies the person hasn't adopted either and the OP also said that the word should mean someone without any children.)

Comment: I would understand this word, even though I haven't seen it specifically before, because -para/-parous comes up in pregnancy. My mother is still indignant about having "elderly multipara" written on the board next to her name when she was in labor with one of my younger brothers (it's medical shorthand for "woman over 35, who has had more than one child"). Note that if you want to specify that the woman has never been pregnant at all, you would need to use ***nulligravida***, since the *-parous* ending specifically counts only pregnancies which make it to viability (usually 20 weeks).

Comment: @chrylis if child-free is loaded then nonbreeder even more so.  @ Gergana and again, just what do you mean by "yet"?  Is there some sort of unstated expectation there?  In any case, here are some sentences: "The young woman hadn't had children, but wanted them in the future. She was a typical *wannabe.*"  "Pregnant and *wannabe pregnant* women are blah blah blah..."  Also: *maid/maiden* implies a young woman who has never been pregnant; the biology behind that is that pregnancy causes hormonal changes that alter the typical "youthful" look of young women.

Comment: "Child-free" seems like a good answer. (@chrylis I can't possibly see how it is politically loaded; what does politics have to do with having children or not?)

Comment: There is a "political" idea that having children is expected and that not wanting to do so means there's something wrong with you.  This is not right.

Answer (score 2):

It’s not a great choice, since this isn’t the usual meaning of the word, but if the only other options are medical jargon unknown to the wider English-speaking world, it might be worth considering. (But honestly I just don’t think you should use this, or the jargon—just use a phrase to explain it.)

Anyway, there is a case for using ***maid*** or ***maiden*** in this way. To be clear, I can find no dictionary which defines it this way—and in general, barring a particular context, it would be understood as signifying that the woman is unwed and/or a virgin (as in every dictionary I could find).

Nonetheless, there is at least one circumstance in which I have heard *maiden* to mean specifically *without children*—the choice of whether the woman is a bride’s *maid of honor* or *matron of honor*.

Basically, here you have a clash between a traditional ritual, a wedding, with its associated historical assumptions, and the modern relaxation of sexual mores. These two terms reflect a historical assumption that a woman is either virginal, unwed, and without children (a *maid*), or else is none of those things (a *matron*, i.e. *mother*). Or, at least, an assumption that in polite company, we shouldn’t draw attention to the possibility of a woman to be some but not all of those things.

These days, in many cultures, sex before marriage is not remotely the taboo it once was. Children out of wedlock isn’t that big a deal in a lot of circles, either. Neither is necessarily shameful or something to avoid mentioning. But a bride is still supposed to have either a *maid* or *matron* of honor. Since *matron* means *mother*, labeling the bride’s sister or best friend or whatever *maid of honor* if she has no children and *matron of honor* if she does have children is a reasonable choice, and I have heard this done.

On the other hand, I have also heard *maid of honor* applied to married women with children (ignoring the less-known term *matron of honor* entirely). I have also heard *matron of honor* applied to women who are wed but without children (e.g. my wife in a friend’s upcoming wedding—though the term may have been chosen to differentiate her from the *maid of honor*, since the bride also has a maid of honor, who is unwed).

So ultimately, in this one context, *maid* or *maiden* **might** have the meaning you desire. But I don’t see a good way to export this meaning to other situations. The only reason it works in this context is because the artificial constraint that either *maid* or *matron* be used, and a woman without children is arguably closer to a *maid* than she is to a *matron*, maybe.

Answer (score -1):

**spinster**

an unmarried woman, typically an older woman beyond the usual age for marriage.

**Maiden** is another synonym. I have heard this Enid Blytons books. Although it has a context of an older woman, but it can usually be used for young unmarried girls. My ex girlfriend's username had spinster in it.

Comment: Being a spinster does not preclude the possibility of having borne children. It suggests virginity but it doesn't mean it. Ahh, the answer! A virgin (woman) has never given birth. Well... only once but that was a long time ago.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The opposite is also true. A woman who has not given birth is not necessarily a virgin. Indeed in almost all cases (except miracles and some cases of the use of donated sperm) a woman who is pregnant with her _first_ child (so has never given birth) is not a virgin.